# how to know which element invoke ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I just want to get the id of the html element that invoke the ajax request, so i can use this data on the controller function.

This is the view:

```
   @model CmsSite.Models.SideBarData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>

<aside id="sidebar">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowContent", "SideBar"))
 {  
         <input id="side_bar_manage_categoty" name="side_bar_manage_categoty" class="post-transaction" type="submit" value="Manage Categorys" />
         <input name="side_bar_manage_products" class="post-transaction" type="submit" value="Manage Products" />
         <input name="side_bar_manage_users" class="post-transaction" type="submit" value="Manage Users" />
         <input name="side_bar_Watch_sales" class="post-transaction" type="submit" value="Watch Sales" />
         <input name="side_bar_change_site_appearance" class="post-transaction" type="submit" value="Change Site Appearance" />
 }
        </aside>  
<div ><p class="content"></p></div>

  <script id="ajax-request-result" type="application/html-template">             
        <div class="content">{{request_result}}</div>
     </script>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.post-transaction').on("click", function () {

                var form = $(this).parent("form");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize()
                })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        var template = $("#ajax-request-result").clone().html();

                        var html =
                            template
                                    .replace("{{request_result}}", data.request_result);
                       $(".content").replaceWith(html);

                    })
                    .error(function () {
                        alert("Your bid has been rejected");
                    });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

this is the contoller with the method that get the ajax requests:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShowContent(string side_bar_manage_categoty)
        {

            string a = side_bar_manage_categoty;
            return Json(new
            {
                request_result = "Transaction Failed!"
            });
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Form elements need `name` attributes.  So if you do something like this:

```
<input id="side_bar_manage_categoty" name="side_bar_manage_categoty" class="post-transaction" type="submit" value="Manage Categorys" />
<input id="side_bar_manage_products" name="side_bar_manage_products" class="post-transaction" type="submit" value="Manage Products" />
```

Then those names (which I just copied from the `id` attributes in this case) will carry values to the `FormCollection` on the server.  So if your action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ShowContent(FormCollection collection)
```

Then you can inspect the `collection` object within the action method to see if it has a key/value for any particular button on the page.  You can even take it a step further and use MVC's form binding to create strongly-typed action method arguments:

```
public ActionResult ShowContent(string side_bar_manage_categoty, string side_bar_manage_products)
```

In this case, if you click the button for `side_bar_manage_products` then that `string` will contain the value `"Manage Categorys"` (since that's the `value` attribute in the `input`) and the other string will be `null`.  If you click the other button, the opposite will be true.  So you'd just test for the non-null string (`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is a good way to test for that) and that will be the invoked button.

Comment: i try to do this like your second method

Comment: @user1310492: Did you add the `name` attribute to the `input`?  Also, given that it's spelled incorrectly, did you consistently maintain the spelling of the name?  It has to be the same in the method signature as it is in the `name` attribute.

Comment: yes the name= and the string parameter in the method are same

Comment: @user1310492: Can you update the question to show the new code?

Comment: @user1310492: Interesting.  It's working fine when I run it on my machine.  I notice also that you've tagged the question with `jQuery-ajax`, are you doing something else with the form post before submitting it?  Where is the jQuery or AJAX?

Comment: The query function is inside the view , I will upload this when I get home ,thank you

Comment: i have upload all the view.

Comment: it works now after i deleted the 
data: form.serialize() from the ajax call
but.. only on explorer :-(

Comment: @user1310492: Ah, you're manually overriding the form post.  That's what was missing from the original context.  The concept should still work, it's just a matter of how you post the data to the server.  Your best bet at this point is to open up something like FireBug (or whatever your browser debugger of choice is) and capture examples of the post.  Once without any JavaScript (just a standard form post), once with the form serialization, etc.  Compare them to see what's different.  The standard post will be "correctly" formed, your manual post should try to mimic its behavior.